# Сериализация модели EF с циклической зависимостью

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Пытаюсь сериализовать модель базы данных. Но выходит ошибка.

Вот моя модель:

```
public class Equipment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        //Двигатель
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Двигатель")]
        public int Engine { get; set; }
        //Количество лошадиных сил
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Мощность")]
        public int Power { get; set; }
        //Год выпуска
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Год выпуска")]
        public int ReleaseYear { get; set; }
        //Тип привода
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Тип привода")]
        public string DriveType { get; set; }
        //КПП
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "КПП")]
        public string Transmission { get; set; }
        //Кузов
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Кузов")]
        public string Body { get; set; }
        //Максимальная скорость
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Максимальная скорость")]
        public int MaxSpeed { get; set; }
        //Вес
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Вес")]
        public int Weight { get; set; }
        //Бак
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Бак")]
        public int MaxFuelVolume { get; set; }
        //Цвет автомобиля
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Цвет")]
        public string Color { get; set; }
        //Изорбражение автомобиля
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Изображение автомобиля")]
        public string Picture { get; set; }

        public int CarModelId { get; set; }
        public virtual CarModel CarModel { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }

        public Equipment()
        {
            Cars = new List<Car>();
        }
    }
```

Вот мой код в контроллере для сериализации:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(car.Equipment);
```

Вот какую ошибку выдаёт:

> Self referencing loop detected with type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Equipment_4B2DAA6CED521984C9D15F5FEA2BB989D5DB7F80683721A0FC847726CB1C9ACB'. Path 'CarModel.Equipments'.

Вот класс на который ругается:

```
public class CarModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Модель")]
        public string ModelName { get; set; }

        public int MarkId { get; set; }
        public virtual Mark Mark { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Equipment> Equipments { get; set; }

        public CarModel()
        {
            Equipments = new List<Equipment>();
        }
    }
```

Пробовал подключить `System.web.script.serialization` и ставил атрибут скрипт игнор на

```
public virtual CarModel CarModel { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }
```

В классе `equipment` и на

```
public virtual ICollection<Equipment> Equipments { get; set; }
```

В классе CarModel, всё равно та же ошибка.

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно избежать этой ошибки? И как можно сериализовать модель с цикличной зависимостью?

ajax запрос:

```
$('#autoList').on('change', function () {
        var ddlAuto = $('#autoList').val();
        if (!ddlAuto || ddlAuto === '')
            return false;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Administration/GetCarInfo",
            data: {
                "carId": ddlAuto
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert('ОК');
            }
        });
    });
```

Результат сериализации если в контроллере написать

```
return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(car.Equipment, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
            }));

"{
  "$id": "1",
  "CarModel": {
    "$id": "2",
    "Equipments": [
      {
        "$ref": "1"
      }
    ],
    "Mark": {
      "$id": "3",
      "CarModels": [
        {
          "$ref": "2"
        },
        {
          "$id": "4",
          "Equipments": [
            {
              "$id": "5",
              "CarModel": {
                "$ref": "4"
              },
              "Cars": [
                {
                  "$id": "6",
                  "Equipment": {
                    "$ref": "5"
                  },
                  "Orders": [
                    {
                      "$id": "7",
                      "Cars": {
                        "$ref": "6"
                      },
                      "Clients": {
                        "$id": "8",
                        "Orders": [
                          {
                            "$ref": "7"
                          },
                          {
                            "$id": "9",
                            "Cars": {
                              "$id": "10",
                              "Equipment": {
                                "$id": "11",
                                "CarModel": {
                                  "$ref": "4"
                                },
                                "Cars": [
                                  {
                                    "$ref": "10"
                                  }
                                ],
                                "Id": 30,
                                "Engine": 2500,
                                "Power": 170,
                                "ReleaseYear": 2011,
                                "DriveType": "Передний",
                                "Transmission": "Автомат",
                                "Body": "Седан",
                                "MaxSpeed": 220,
                                "Weight": 1800,
                                "MaxFuelVolume": 80,
                                "Color": "Чёрный"
```

Comment: Передай конфигурацию в JsonConvert.SerializeObject вторым параметром: ```new JsonSerializerSetting() {  ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore  } ```

Comment: @SultanovShamil так уже пробовал вылетает ошибка `Выдано исключение типа "System.OutOfMemoryException".`

Comment: @SultanovShamil получилось серриализовать если написать в контроллере следующее, `return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(car.Equipment, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
            }));` Но в таком случае сериализуется не в object а в стринг. В вопросе добавляю пример того во что сериализовалось и уже привёл пример моего ajax запроса если это поможет.

Comment: в чем смысл мешать модель БД с моделью вашего API? Это, по идее, разные слои приложения, который никак друг с другом не пересекаются. Обычно, насколько я помню, когда надо конвертировать модель БД в модель API - используются мапперы (типа AutoMapper).

Comment: @tym32167 ну я для работы с данными в репозиториях использую доменные модели. И в работе с web слоем не делаю каких либо view моделей, а работаю напрямую с доменными.

Comment: @Андрей я это понял, я потому и написал вам, что вы сами себе палки в колеса вставляете

Comment: @tym32167, а ну понял к чему вы это имели в виду. С проблемой уже разобрался внизу в ответе никиты уже описал.

Answer (score 0):

Когда-то мне очень помог атрибут DataContract(IsReference = true) перед классами, которые ссылаются друг на друга.

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]    
public class Equipment
{
   ...
   public virtual CarModel CarModel { get; set; }
   ...
}

[DataContract(IsReference = true)]  
public class CarModel
{
   ...
   public virtual ICollection<Equipment> Equipments { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

В этом случае JSON будет использовать ссылки, которые могут зациктиваться.
А чтобы убрать ошибку с динамическими проксями добавьте в конструктор контекста 
`Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;`

Comment: Nikita, попробовал вашим способом. Вот что у меня вышло в ajax запросе `{"$id":"1"}"`

Comment: Может поможет мой ajax запрос. Код добавил в вопрос.

Comment: Может быть стоит посмотреть в сторону отправки из контроллера представления модели, а не чистой модели?

Comment: Nikita, вы имеете в виду сделать viewModel? Можно конечно, но хотелось бы разобраться как сделать это с помощью сериализации.

Comment: Можно игнорировать (атрибутом) зацикливающие свойства модели при сериализации, если они вам не нужны на фронте. Или использовать json c $id и $ref, для них, правда, придется добавить собственный десериализатор в js, но их много уже готовых.

Comment: Nikita, поглядите в вопросе я добавил всё что у меня получилось сериализовать, и там только стринговская строка, а с вариантом игнора вообще выходит out of memory я всё описал. Если только вы имеете в виду десериализовать то что у меня получилось в виде строки, в объект, то приведите пример как это можно сделать?

Comment: Nikita большое спасибо, навели меня на мысль как мой код доделать до красоты. Добавил на клиенте строчку `var myObject = JSON.parse(data);` и из той строки что я привёл вверху в json формате, я в переменной myObject получаю всю структуру не только equipment но и всей иерархии моего объекта.

Comment: Вариант с игнором свойства при сериализации - это добавить атрибут [JsonIgnore] перед свойством, которое "зацикливает" модель. Вариант с "строкой" это, по моему, вполне валидный json, только не полный. А в качестве примера десериализации такого json можно использовать [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118667/how-to-parse-json-string-contains-circular-reference-in-javascript).

Comment: Nikita как я понял там ссылками класс дополняется. Спасибо за вариант.